# PYTHON Dataframe variable in .loc selector not working as intended

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

Fairly new, trying to figure out why:

```
for index, vendor in enumerate(vendor_file):
        work_frame = main_frame.loc[main_frame['provider'] == vendor]
        print(work_frame.values)
```

returns empty BUT:

```
for index, vendor in enumerate(vendor_file):
        vendor = 'xyz'
        work_frame = main_frame.loc[main_frame['provider'] == vendor]
        print(work_frame.values)
```

works as intended. Originally I thought maybe the variable in the loc statement was the problem, but as you can see that works fine. Really at a loss.

EDIT:  The issue is with this statement:

```
work_frame = main_frame.loc[main_frame['provider'] == vendor]
```

When vendor is assigned from the for loop iterating over a simple text file the response data frame is empty.  However, when I assign the vendor variable manually to the first item found in the file the for loop is iterating it works.

SOLVED:

So I solved it, stupid issue.  The text file had \n that I could not see in my inspections(or text editor).  It worked when I added this line:

```
 vendor = vendor.strip('\n')
```

Final Code:

```
for index, vendor in enumerate(vendor_file):
        vendor = vendor.strip('\n')        
        work_frame = main_frame[main_frame['provider'] == vendor]
```

Comment: work_frame = main_frame[main_frame['provider'] == vendor]. You don't need to have .loc

Comment: What is the issue? What is `vendor` set to in the first example? You should provide an example of the dataframe and the use-case otherwise it's unclear what the confusion is.

Comment: Sorry for the confusion, I hope that clarifies a bit. Also @beegee removing loc has the same empty dataframe issue.

Comment: without the data, difficult to help. To debug, i) try printing out `index, vendor` inside `for` loop. ii) check the column name `provider` and the unique values in it

Comment: So in the data frame the provider column prints out: 'xyz' in the file first line is xyz.  I went so far as trying to manually put in ' in case that was the issue.

Comment: are you sure it's not something simple like a trailing/leading whitespace on the value coming from the file (for example a `\r` that you can't see) - should be easy to determine through inspection of the actual value

Comment: Are you sure there the `vendor` is string when you enumerate `vendor_file`. If not try: `work_frame = main_framec[main_frame['provider'] == str(vendor)]`

Comment: So I solved it, stupid issue.  The text file had \n that I could not see in my inspections.  When I added this line:  vendor = vendor.strip('\n')  it worked.

Answer (score 0):

So I solved it, stupid issue. The text file had \n that I could not see in my inspections(or text editor). It worked when I added this line:

vendor = vendor.strip('\n')

Final Code:

```
for index, vendor in enumerate(vendor_file):
        vendor = vendor.strip('\n')        
        work_frame = main_frame[main_frame['provider'] == vendor]
```

Comment: Can you please consider increasing the reputation for the comments that you found useful for solving the issue that you had.